# Trimming a string value

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to perform what would be a PHP left trim in Perl.

I have the following string value:

```
user1/es/public_html/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg
```

I need to trim everything from the left of '/shop', so my string value will look like this:

```
/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg
```

I have the following which removes white space, is the best solution here to apply 'user1/eschemtrad/public_html' to the reg ex?

```
my $image = $banners[$i]{'imageloc'};

   $image =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Comment: `s/\s+$//` is a right trim

Comment: It's worth noting that this wouldn't be a trim in PHP, either. In most languages, "trim" means to strip whitespace from the beginning of a string, the end of a string, or both.

Comment: Please show the left trim in PHP that you want to emulate

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it:

```
my $str = "user1/es/public_html/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg";
$str =~ s|.*(?=/shop/)||;
print $str; #
```

Output:

```
/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious solution is to *capture* the part you want—everything from `/shop` onwards. Note that I've used braces `{}` instead of the default slash to delimit the regex so that I don't have to escape the slash in the pattern

```
use v5.14;

my $s = 'user1/es/public_html/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg';

say my ($trimmed) = $s =~ m{(/shop.*)};
```

#### output

```
/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Perl. What is the use 'v5.14'; in relation too?

Comment: That enforces certain perl versions, and enables features. In this case `say` - which is like `print` but it adds a line feed automatically.

Comment: @Liam: The doumentation is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). It is equivalent to `use strict` together with `use feature` for all features available to version 14 of Perl 5. I used it here to mainly as a shorthand for `use strict` and `use feature 'say'`. If It were a full program then I would have added those requirements explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the full power of the regular expression engine---and it looks like you don't in this case---then you can use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) instead:

```
my $str = 'user1/es/public_html/shop/images/banners/326583.jpg';
$str = substr($str, index($str, '/shop'));
```